# Looping through a dataframe a JSON Python 2

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python 2 and I want to loop through a JSON generated by a query and return same strings:

This is my JSON:

```json
"{\"Machine\":{\"0\":\"Mach1\",\"1\":\"Mach2\",\"2\":\"Mach3\",\"3\":\"Mach4\",\"4\":\"Mach5\"}}"
```

What I don't understand is which is the key here and how can I loop to get a result like this:

```
Mach1
Mach2
Mach3
..
```

Or even just Mach1.

I've tried this:

```
def printDict(dict):
    for key,v, value in d.iteritems():
        if type(v) is dict:
            printDict(v)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".
```

But doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake:

```
def printDict(dict):
    ...
    if type(v) is dict:
```

`dict` is no longer the built-in dictionary type, you've overwritten it locally. Also `type(v) is dict` is not a good way to check if something is an instance of something else (it doesn't take inheritance into account).

Second mistake:

```
for key,v, value in d.iteritems():
```

`.iteritems()` method returns a sequence of pairs, not triples. Also `d` is an undefined local variable.

Finally

```
print "{0} : {1}".
```

is a syntax error.

Is this what you are looking for:

```
def print_dict(dct):
    for key, value in dct.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_dict(value)
        else:
            print '{0} : {1}'.format(key, value)
```

Also if you start from raw JSON (i.e. a string) then you have to deserialize it first:

```
import json
dct = json.loads(my_json)
```

Comment: @Christian should take attention, that line format (as is) incorrect now, he must clean unnecessary symbols before parsing.

Comment: @RomanMindlin you're absolutely right. I removed the unnecessary symbols before parsing but I still got the indexes: "Machine": {"1": "machine1", "0": "Machine2"}, they are in other order because I put grouped them DESC. Should I worry about them?

Comment: The [specification](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the built-in dictionary type disclaims any preservation of order, it is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of `key: value` pairs